# Subtraction by 1 when solving terms of sequences?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

If Arithmetic and Geometric Sequences are simply Linear and Exponential functions respectively. Why then do we subtract the *n* variable by 1 when solving for certain terms in these sequences?

$$t_n=d(n-1)+a$$

$$t_n=a\cdot r^{n-1}$$

I've tried exploring this question from a graphing perspective and it's clear this results in the sequence index starting at 1 rather then zero but is that really the only reason? Personally I'd rather start sequence indices at 0 as I've found going back and forth between linear equation techniques and sequence term formulas makes it easy to make off by 1 errors if one isn't careful.

Comment: You have given one good reason why mathematicians like to start counting at $0$. A mathematical clock would have the hour labels $0$ to $11$. And $0$ would be on the extreme right of the clock, not on top. And the numbers would increase counterclockwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using $n$ instead of $n-1$. It'll give you the same sequence, only shifted by 1. For example, suppose that we have two sequences
$$
t_n=3(n-1)+2\qquad s_n=3n+2
$$
then we'll have
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &\dots\\ \hline
t_n & 2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14 &\dots\\
s_n & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 17
\end{array}
There's no real difference between the two. Some sequences (especially those defined recursively) have properties that are more tidily defined when they start at a particular index, but as long as you're careful you can shift the terms in a sequence (or a series, for that matter) by any amount you wish.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a matter of the indexing set you choose. Sometimes we choose $I=\{0,1,2,\dots\}=\Bbb N_0$ and sometimes $I=\{1,2,3,\dots\}=\Bbb N$. Using the former, we can write

$$\{t_n\}_{n \in I}\;\,/\;\,t_n=a\cdot r^n$$

and using the latter

$$\{t_n\}_{n \in I}\;\,/\;\,t_n=a\cdot r^{n-1}$$

There is no more mystery than that.

Answer (score 0):

I often like to make
the initial term have index $n_0$,
so the result can be interpreted
whether the initial index is $0$ or $1$.